# flexbox won't overflow with justify-content: flex-end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a chat with css flexbox, and as I want my messages to be diplay bottom of a container, I used `justify-content: flex-end` but when I have to many messages the div isn't scrollable with `overflow: auto`

I've read about a solution which is to reverse my `.messages` div and my `.write-zone` div and to replace `flex-direction: column-reverse` but this isn't a good solution for me because the content of my `.messages` div is dynamic, messages will be added and the scroll level won't follow, and I'd like to avoid controlling the scroll in javascript.

Does someone know any solution or trick to do this ?

Here's a fiddle showing skeleton of my code :

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.messages {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.message {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.message.user {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #2bf;
}

.message.other {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.write-zone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

input {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div><div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="write-zone">
    <input type="text" />
    <button>
    send
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your issue.  Can you rephrase it in another way?  What is specifically wrong with your code sample?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your issue is. What _should_ it look like (vs what your snippet outputs)?

Comment: The problem is how should the browser set a scroll bar, if the content is already shown at the bottom? To understand what I mean just remove `justify-content: flex-end;` from `.messages`. I think you have to use javascript to scroll to the last message.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You were almost there!

Two things that you can do to get you closer:

1. To prevent the flex items from collapsing ( dividing itself among the space of the container it's placed in ) is to set an explicit min-height instead of just a height
2. Create a container div that wraps your messages:  `.messages-container` and give this an explicit max-height and overflow auto.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="messages">
    <div class="messages-container"> <!-- New Wrapping Container -->
       <div class="message user">
```

**CSS:**

```
    .message {
      min-height: 80px;
    }

   .messages-container {
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 300px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
   .messages{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-end;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.messages-container {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.messages{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: auto;
}

.message {
  margin: 5px;
  min-height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.message.user {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #2bf;
}

.message.other {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.write-zone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

input {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
  <div class="messages-container">
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div><div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="write-zone">
    <input type="text" />
    <button>
    send
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TheoHolander awesome, glad to hear! Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you’re trying to have the messages align from the bottom and move up if new ones appear.

Using `justify-content: flex-end` on the container is correct, but if `.messages` is taking all available height, that still has no effect.

From `.messages`, remove the `height: 100%` and replace its `justify-content: flex-end` (which seems unnecessary) with `margin-top: auto` and I think you’ll be a step further.

```
.messages {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

So the ‘trick’ you’re looking for is an auto margin: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your trying to make the chatbox scrollable when there are a lot of messages.

I found that by removing the justify-content flex-end from the .messages I'm able to scroll through the messages.

Hope this helps.

```css
.container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.messages-container {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.messages{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*   justify-content: flex-end; */
  overflow: auto;
}

.message {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.message.user {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #2bf;
}

.message.other {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.write-zone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

input {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="messages">
  <div class="messages-container">
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div><div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    <div class="message user">
      Toto
    </div>
    <div class="message other">
      Titi
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="write-zone">
    <input type="text" />
    <button>
    send
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works indeed but when I have only few messages, they won't be aligned at bottom.
EDIT : it will works if I don't set any height for `.messages`